# creating a web interface that displays live data from hardware

Tags: python

I am trying to create a web interface to display some data that is being extracted live from a piece of hardware.

I have already written a program using pyQt that extracts data every second. I was wondering if it is possible to simultaneously push this data to a web interface with Python.

I want the webpage to not continuously refresh as data is coming in every second. Charts are essential, I have to have the ability to plot the data that is being pushed.

Can anyone suggest me how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Relevant: [How to detect changes in firebase child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45166966/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most conventional way to go about this would be to write some server-side code to communicate with the device, and save responses (all of them? the most recent *n*?) to a database. You'd expose this to a REST API, which you'd then call at a specified interval using AJAX from the browser.