# Serial data Communication via Server on Python

Tags: php, python, mysql, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I would like to make a project in which Temperature of controller will be accessed remotely.

The details of it are as under.
i am envisaging to make something like the following:

1) Serial data will be taken every hour from the Temperature Controller via RS 232 or RS 485 port and will be transferred to raspberry pi.
2) Raspberry Pi will transmit the data to a server.
3) This data will be accessed from that server on multiple mobile devices(both ios and Android).
4) On mobile it can be either in the form of an application or idk someother type.

This is the whole concept.
At this point i am able to perform the first point but i am not sure how to do the rest of the points, if someone can guide me how to do it so i can do a reading of those things and get on with the project.

Thanks.

Comment: Read [How to detect changes in firebase child with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45166966/7414759)

Comment: There are many ways to do it, since you have data stored in RPi, one way you could do is setup a web server on RPi, and write the application for mobile devices to access the data (i.e. your step 2, 3 and 4). Those links might help you get started, https://www.e-tinkers.com/2017/04/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-data-logger/, https://www.e-tinkers.com/2017/09/ds18b20-data-analysis-using-pandas/ and https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/